# Can I use the == operator to compare Point objects in Java?

Tags: java, object-comparison, object-identity

While i am solving the questions from the book "cracking the coding interview"...
i got a doubt.the question is:

Given two squares on a two dimensional plane, find a line that would cut these two
squares in half.

Solution:Any line that goes through the center of a rectangle must cut it in half. Therefore, if you drew
a line connecting the centers of the two squares, it would cut both in half.

```
   public class Square {
       public double left;
       public double top;
       public double bottom;
       public double right;
       public Square(double left, double top, double size) {
              this.left = left;
              this.top = top;
              this.bottom = top + size;
              this.right = left + size;
       }

       public Point middle() {
              return new Point((this.left + this.right) / 2,
                                           (this.top + this.bottom) / 2);
       }

       public Line cut(Square other) {
              Point middle_s = this.middle();
              Point middle_t = other.middle();
              if (middle_s == middle_t) {
                     return new Line(new Point(left, top),
                     new Point(right, bottom));
              } else {
                     return new Line(middle_s, middle_t);
              }
       }
}
```

But now the doubt is '==' operator in cut method to check whether they are points of same square. Is Point immutable?? kindly help me...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're comparing objects references  not the content itself

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter if `Point` is immutable.  What matters is that the `==` is doing a pointer/reference comparison.  It is checking to see if `middle_s` and `middle_t` reference the same Object instance, not whether or not they are the same in terms of their internal fields.

What you probably want to do is implement/override `equals()` for the `Point` class such that it compares the `x` and `y` coordinates, and returns true if they match.  Then you can compare your points by doing `if (middle_s.equals(middle_t))`.

When you override `equals()`, be sure you also override `hashCode()` accordingly, as well.

Comment: The exact rules are covered quite well in the [Object.equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter whether Point is immutable... the real question still remains.

What's important is whether you care about the *identity* of the point objects--whether they are the same instance--or you care about the *value* of the point objects.

Here, clearly you care about the value of the point, not which object instance it is, so you should be using `middle_s.equals(middle_t)`.

Comment: ya.. this is what i am thinking about...middle() method always returns a new Point object ..irrespective of equals method is overrriden , we can't  use == to compare object refernces ..isn't it??

Comment: @hareenda: You can use `==` **only** to compare the references, and the result will always be `false` for new objects (even if they correspond to the same geometric point).

Answer (score 0):

From [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), you can use `equals` method to compare two `Point` object.

In additional: let take a look at [Android developer's page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for more explanation:

> Compares this instance with the specified object and indicates if they
>   are equal. In order to be equal, o must represent the same object as
>   this instance using a class-specific comparison. The general contract
>   is that this comparison should be reflexive, symmetric, and
>   transitive. Also, no object reference other than null is equal to null